# activeMQ on linux server and Windows client

Tags: c#, linux, activemq-classic

I will work with ActiveMQ installed on a Linux server. 
As I'm developing in C#, I'm thinking of making a queue management program (which I call "windows client"). 
For each message received in a queue, my windows client must trigger a specific C# executable (associate to the type of message).

**My question:** I installed and tested activeMQ on Windows and my C# program works. 
However can I read ActiveMQ queues from a Linux server from a C# windows program?
Thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ supports a number of messaging protocols which can interoperate across platforms without issue.